# How can you send in c# from serial port data and after to disconnet and reconnect without crashing?

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-forms-designer, serial-communication

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        cmbPort.Items.AddRange(ports);
        cmbPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort!= null && serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort.DataReceived -= DataReceivedEvent;
            serialPort.Close();
        }
    }

    private void BtnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnConnect.Enabled = false;
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;
        try
        {
            serialPort.PortName = cmbPort.Text;
            serialPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedEvent;
            serialPort.Open();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void BtnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnConnect.Enabled = true;
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
        try
        {

            serialPort.DataReceived -= DataReceivedEvent;
            serialPort.Close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    void DataReceivedEvent(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort.IsOpen == true)
        {

            int suma = 0;
            SerialPort senderPort = (SerialPort) sender;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2];

            if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
            {
                int val_magica1 = (int) (buffer[0]);
                suma += val_magica1;
                if (val_magica1 == 100)
                {
                    if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                    {
                        int val_magica2 = (int) (buffer[0]);
                        suma += val_magica2;

                        if (val_magica2 == 98)
                            if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                            {
                                int poz = (int) (buffer[0]);
                                suma += poz;
                                if (poz == 1)
                                    if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                    {
                                        int data = (int) (buffer[0]);
                                        suma += data;
                                        if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                        {
                                            int suma_primita = (int) (buffer[0]);
                                            suma = suma % 256;
                                            Console.WriteLine("Suma soft1: " + suma);
                                            Console.WriteLine("Suma arduino1: " + suma_primita);
                                            if (suma == suma_primita)
                                            {
                                                SetText1(Convert.ToString(data));

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                if (poz == 2)
                                    if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                    {
                                        int data = (int) (buffer[0]);
                                        suma += data;
                                        if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                        {
                                            int suma_primita = (int) (buffer[0]);
                                            suma = suma % 256;
                                            Console.WriteLine("Suma soft2: " + suma);
                                            Console.WriteLine("Suma arduino2: " + suma_primita);
                                            if (suma == suma_primita)
                                                SetText2(Convert.ToString(data));
                                        }
                                    }

                                if (poz == 3)
                                    if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                    {
                                        int data = (int) (buffer[0]);
                                        suma += data;
                                        if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                        {
                                            int suma_primita = (int) (buffer[0]);
                                            suma = suma % 256;
                                            Console.WriteLine("Suma soft3: " + suma);
                                            Console.WriteLine("Suma arduino3: " + suma_primita);
                                            if (suma == suma_primita)
                                                SetText3(Convert.ToString(data));
                                        }
                                    }

                                if (poz == 4)
                                    if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                    {
                                        int data = (int) (buffer[0]);
                                        suma += data;
                                        if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                        {
                                            int suma_primita = (int) (buffer[0]);
                                            suma = suma % 256;
                                            Console.WriteLine("Suma soft4: " + suma);
                                            Console.WriteLine("Suma arduino4: " + suma_primita);
                                            if (suma == suma_primita)
                                                SetText4(Convert.ToString(data));
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return;

        serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
    }
    private void SetText1(string text)
    {

        if (this.afisare1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText1);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.afisare1.Text = text;
        }
    }
    private void SetText2(string text)
    {

        if (this.afisare2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText2);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.afisare2.Text = text;
        }
    }

    private void SetText3(string text)
    {

        if (this.afisare3.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText3);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.afisare3.Text = text;
        }
    }
    private void SetText4(string text)
    {

        if (this.afisare4.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText4);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.afisare4.Text = text;
        }
    }

    private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(send.Text);
        if(serialPort.IsOpen)
        serialPort.Write(data,0,0);
    }
```

The application is 4 potentiometers that are sending at the same time to a c# application data. Everything is working fine when I am connecting, but when I try to disconnect it crash, after that I can't reconnect just if I unplug and plug again the USB. Instead, I get the following error: 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request'.

Comment: You have a threading issue; data is probably still being fired from the DataReceived event and you have the port closed.  You'll need to stop receiving messages then close the port. Or the easy fix is to close the port on a different thread.

Comment: It's my first time when i am working with threads so can you explain me how to do that?

Comment: Easiest way is to use `BackgroundWorker`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/backgroundworker-component-overview You will call your background worker to do work async and in there you can call `SerialPort1.close()`.